# How do I declare the type of an array index in swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, enums, indices

Am trying to create a 2D lookup table with enums representing the axes of the table in swift 4, for example:

```
enum ECT: Int {
  case cool = 0
  case normal
  case above_range
}

enum Load: Int {
  case idle = 0
  case cruise
  case wot
}

var timingRetard = [[Double?]](repeating: [nil,nil,nil], count 3)
```

(no, I'm not writing embedded PCM code in Swift (tho that would be fun!), but its a simple example for the swift construct I'm trying to use but haven't figured out the syntax)

how can assign & retrieve values in the array using the enum as an index, e.g. assuming the element has already been created

```
timingRetard[cool][idle] = 0.0
timingRetard[cool][cruise] = 0.0
timingRetard[cool][wot] = 0.0
timingRetard[above_range][wot] = -8.0
timingRetard[normal][cruise] = 0.0
```

How do I declare index types of a Swift array to be only accessed by the enum types after init'ing the array given the number of enums for each axis?  I figured I could add timingRetard to a struct and declare a subscript method to constrain the indexes to the enum types, but haven't gotten that to work either.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve is to override subscript method in a struct. It is explained much better [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html). I used the example mentioned in the link to solve your problem in this way:

```
enum ECT: Int{
    case cool = 0
    case normal
    case above_range
}

enum Load: Int {
    case idle = 0
    case cruise
    case wot
}

struct TimingRetard2D {
    let rows: Int, cols: Int
    private(set) var array:[Double?]

    init(rows: Int, cols: Int, repeating:Double?) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        array = Array(repeating: repeating, count: rows * cols)
    }

    private func indexIsValid(row: Int, col: Int) -> Bool {
        return row >= 0 && row < rows && col >= 0 && col < cols
    }

    subscript(row: ECT, col: Load) -> Double? {
        get {
            assert(indexIsValid(row: row.rawValue, col: col.rawValue), "Index out of range")
            return array[(row.rawValue * cols) + col.rawValue]
        }
        set {
            assert(indexIsValid(row: row.rawValue, col: col.rawValue), "Index out of range")
            array[(row.rawValue * cols) + col.rawValue] = newValue
        }
    }
}

var timingRetard = TimingRetard2D.init(rows: 3, cols: 3, repeating: nil)
timingRetard[.cool, .idle] = 0.0
timingRetard[.cool, .cruise] = 0.0
timingRetard[.cool, .wot] = 0.0
timingRetard[.above_range, .wot] = -8.0
timingRetard[.normal, .cruise] = 0.0
print(timingRetard.array)
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

[Optional(0.0), Optional(0.0), Optional(0.0), nil, Optional(0.0), nil, nil, nil, Optional(-8.0)]

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed work.  However I updated it a bit to mimic a true swift array of arrays in the event it ever needs to extract or update the entire row.  See below

Answer (score 0):

Minor update to Puneet's solution, which allows the array of arrays instead of calculating offsets into a single dimensional array:

```
enum ECT: Int{
    case cool = 0
    case normal
    case above_range
}

enum Load: Int {
    case idle = 0
    case cruise
    case wot
}

struct TimingRetard2D {
    let rows: Int, cols: Int
    private(set) var array:[[Double?]]

    init(rows: Int, cols: Int, repeating:Double?) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        let initRow = Array(repeating: repeating, count: cols)
        array = Array(repeating: initRow, count: rows)
    }

    private func indexIsValid(row: Int, col: Int) -> Bool {
        return row >= 0 && row < rows && col >= 0 && col < cols
    }

    subscript(row: ECT, col: Load) -> Double? {
        get {
            assert(indexIsValid(row: row.rawValue, col: col.rawValue), "Index out of range")
            return array[row.rawValue][col.rawValue]
        }
        set {
            assert(indexIsValid(row: row.rawValue, col: col.rawValue), "Index out of range")
            array[row.rawValue][col.rawValue] = newValue
        }
    }
}

var timingRetard = TimingRetard2D.init(rows: 3, cols: 3, repeating: nil)
timingRetard[.cool, .idle] = 0.0
timingRetard[.cool, .cruise] = 0.0
timingRetard[.cool, .wot] = 0.0
timingRetard[.above_range, .wot] = -8.0
timingRetard[.normal, .cruise] = 0.0
print(timingRetard.array)
```

However is there also away to make the consumer of the struct to also use 2D array syntax? e.g. timingRetards[.cool][.wot]

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
extension Array where Element == Double? {
    subscript(load: Load) -> Element {
        get {
            return self[load.rawValue]
        }
        set {
            self[load.rawValue] = newValue
        }
    }
}

extension Array where Element == [Double?] {
    subscript(ect: ECT) -> Element {
        get {
            return self[ect.rawValue]
        }
        set {
            self[ect.rawValue] = newValue
        }
    }
}


var timingRetard = [[Double?]](repeating: [nil,nil,nil], count: 3)

timingRetard[.cool][.idle] = 0.0
timingRetard[.cool][.cruise] = 0.0
timingRetard[.cool][.wot] = 0.0
timingRetard[.above_range][.wot] = -8.0
timingRetard[.normal][.cruise] = 0.0
```

But, it seems better to extend your `TimingRetard2D`.